# TFS 2018 Manage permissions issue for service account on build server

Tags: tfs

I have a service account which has Project Administrator permissions but when I try to connect that account as an agent from the build server I get the error "Access Denied. User needs Manage permissions for pool Default to perform this action." The Project Administrators account has all items set to Allow. This same service account is set as Build Administrator at the collection level. Does anyone understand how to setup a service account used on a build server in order to become an agent for a project and/or collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add the user as the `Administrator` role in the Default pool.

Navigate to `http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool?poolId=1&_a=roles`
Then add the user..

If that still not work, then you can try to add the user as the "**TFS Administrator**"

Team Foundation Server Administration Console > Application Tier > Group Membership > Team Foundation Administrators

[image]

Comment: I do not think it is a good practice to add the service as a Team Foundation Administrator. I did add the service account as part of the administrators group for the pool and the agent connected successfully.

Comment: @BWW So what about only adding the user as the `Administrator` role in the Default pool? is that working?

Comment: I added the service account to the Administrator's group and it worked fine.